# How to remove animation from react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

How can I disable animations from `react-native-router-flux`?

I tried with adding `transitionConfig` but it doesn't work. The version of `react-native-router-flux` is **4.0.0-beta.21**

The scenes are as follows:

```
const transitionConfig = () => ({
    transitionSpec: {
        duration: 0,
        timing: Animated.timing,
        easing: Easing.step0,
    },
});

const Entry = () => (
    <Router getSceneStyle={getSceneStyle} createReducer={reducerCreate} transitionConfig={transitionConfig}>
        <Scene key="root">
            <Scene key="scene_login"
                   component={Login}
                   title={gettext("Login")}
                   initial={true}
                   type="reset"
                   hideTabBar
                   hideNavBar
                   navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
                   titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleStyle} />                      
            <Scene key="scene_condition"
                   tabs={true}
                   type="reset"
                   tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}
                   tabBarSelectedItemStyle={styles.tabBarSelectedItemStyle}
                   navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
                   titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleStyle}
                   hideTabBar={false}
                   hideNavBar={true}
                   tabBarPosition="bottom"
                   labelStyle={{fontSize: 7}}
                   title="">
                <Scene key="scene_condition_car"
                       tabBarLabel={gettext("Model")}
                       title={gettext("Model")}
                       component={Car}
                       icon={TabIcon}
                       iconTittleHidden
                       iconName="directions-car"
                       leftButtonIconStyle={styles.moduleButton}
                       leftButtonImage={require('./img/icons/left.png')}
                       onLeft={(props) => requestOverview(props.request.id)}
                       navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
                       titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleStyle}/>
                <Scene key="scene_condition_checks_features"
                       tabBarLabel={gettext("Equipment")}
                       title={gettext("Equipment")}
                       component={Equipment}
                       icon={TabIcon}
                       iconTittleHidden
                       iconName="playlist-add-check"
                       leftButtonIconStyle={styles.moduleButton}
                       leftButtonImage={require('./img/icons/left.png')}
                       onLeft={(props) => requestOverview(props.request.id)}
                       navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
                       titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleStyle}/>
                <Scene key="scene_condition_specs"
                       tabBarLabel={gettext("Specifications")}
                       title={gettext("Specifications")}
                       labelStyle={{fontSize: 18}}
                       component={CarSpecs}
                       icon={TabIcon}
                       iconTittleHidden
                       iconName="control-point-duplicate"
                       leftButtonIconStyle={styles.moduleButton}
                       leftButtonImage={require('./img/icons/left.png')}
                       onLeft={(props) => requestOverview(props.request.id)}
                       navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
                       titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleStyle}/>
            </Scene>
        </Scene>
    </Router>
);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same a month ago and **i solved it by using**

```
duration={0}
```

on the main  component or on the specific scenes you want. Try this and let us know

Comment: my suggestion in that case is to drop back to a more stable version on what you need and i suggest @3.38.0. That would be what i would do

Answer (score 1):

I am on an older version of `router-flux`, but I utilize `getSceneStyle` to handle the transitions, like so:

```
export function noAnimation(props): Object {
  const {
    // layout,
    position,
    scene,
  } = props;

  const index = scene.index;
                // [willGainFocus, isFocused, lostFocus]
  const inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 1];
  // const height = layout.initHeight;

  const opacity = position.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: ([1, 1, 1]: Array<number>),
  });

  const scale = position.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: ([1, 1, 1]: Array<number>),
  });

  const translateX = 0;
  const translateY = position.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: ([0, 0, -0]: Array<number>),
  });

  return {
    opacity,
    transform: [
      { scale },
      { translateX },
      { translateY },
    ],
  };
}
```

Comment: (just pass that function to `getSceneStyle`)

Answer (score 0):

i solved by using

```
animationEnabled={false}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Router transitionConfig={{animationEnabled:false}}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 